# Convert date and time in R?

Tags: r

I have a function in my code that reads as:

```
total.test <- total %>%
  mutate(
    event_start = mdy_hms(paste(Date, Time)))
```

However, I think that I need to reformat my `Date` and `Time` variable to reflect what is needed in the function. Currently values within my `Date` variable read as mm/dd/yy (such as 7/30/21) and the `Time` variable reads as hh:mm (such as
14:20)

The above function worked fine when the `Date` originally read as mm/dd/yyyy (such as 8/23/2022) and the `Time` variable read as hh:mm:ss (such as 15:21:41).

Either I will need to reformat my variables, or change the above function.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you just use `mdy_hm` or is the issue that you have a mix of both hh::mm and hh:mm::ss?

Comment: The issue is not the year but rather the seconds. The function you are using `mdy_hms` requires your datetime to have seconds, yet you only have hours and minutes. Therefore you need to use `mdy_hm` as @JonSpring suggested

Comment: Thanks! Worked with mdy_hm. I was actually able to use a mix of hh:mm and hh:mm:ss